# commission junction and other affiliate network do they have sandbox? how to test drive? i am using popshops

Tags: affiliate, commission-junction

i am developing an affiliate site.

it uses linkshare and commission junction.

it is for our client. so i do not have any account with any network or agent. either with popshops or the networks.

the client has registered with popshops to display merchants.

when users click links we need to know which user had purchased which product by sending some information to affiliate networks using the sid option.

every thing fine except a sandbox.

how do we do a test drive with link share and commission junction?

else we have to wait till an user purchases a product.

any suggestion and comments would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't offer a sandbox, you will need to just know what the API results will be.

It is pretty well documented, but that's all they offer.

If you want, I recommend buying something from one of your affiliates and use that piece of info for testing. Most affiliates don't mind, and I have never found anything in a contract that mentions the affiliate using their own link.

Comment: Yes. People said that we have to buy something for least amount to do a test drive. and in comission junction page they have specified that they dont offer a sandbox.

Comment: When I needed test data, I actually found something I wanted with one of my affiliates.

Comment: oh so with the help of test data we can see what are all the fields they return and according to that we can write the code. Yes a sample return value with possibilities will do good. we are registered with CJ and LS. do they both have test data. As you had said they should. Isn't it? or can i see a test data in any website?

Comment: I don't know, and I haven't worked with LinkShares APIs. I'm sorry I can't provide sample data, but with some googling you should be able to find something.